# SSH in to an Android phone with out using the screen

Tags: ssh, android

I recently bought a Android phone at a yard sell and it has some respectable Specs but the screen is broken and i cant find a replacement for it... I want to ssh in to it so i can use its CPU for a robot i have laying around. My question is can i gain SSH access without using a screen to set up? I can communicate with the file system via micro SD and USB. this is a [link](http://www.kyocera-wireless.com/event-phone/pdf/Event_Virgin_Mobile_Spec_Sheet.pdf) to the phones Specs.

Comment: Have you verified the phone is working ? If not, you could try access through ADB for starters.  Then go on to the SSH option. SSH is workable, but you would most likely get only the shell.

Answer (score 0):

Hey I post here in the hope to help future people.

http://www.leathan.net/AxE/tutorials.html

Its the only tutorial I have on that page so dont laugh at me. But basically what you do is what Ashish recommended. Only after you get adb access you push a VNC app with a CLI. you then launch the app and then you can fully controll your phone. display and all. I recommend DroidSSH server Pro as a good app. On the phone I have with a broken screen I used the above method went to Play, downloaded droid ssh and use my phone as an apache/irc server now :)

GL

Comment: The post is broken unfortunately :-(